# examine the variables when running python script in python environment?

Tags: python, bash

I run my python script after launching Python environment in bash. Then I want to examine a variable defined in my script. But I cannot. I wonder how I can run the script in Python while still being able to examine the variables defined in the script after finish running? Note that I don't want to write the values of the variables to a file or stdout. Thanks!

```
>>> import myscript
>>> myvar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myvar' is not defined
```

Comment: What do you mean by variable here?  Are you referring to an environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to say that the variable is part of your import:

```
import myscript
myscript.myvar
```

or

```
from myscript import *
myvar
```